# How to add a custom emoji library in the native messaging app on the Android?

Tags: android, messaging, emoji

Are there any examples of this out there? I'm new to the mobile app arena, and I know **EmojiCompat** might help, but if there is any guidance someone could suggest or a direction, I would be grateful!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-the-android-emoji-compatibility-library-1b9f3bb724aa